# How much does it costs teams to insure against player injury?

Tags: baseball, finances

In 2008, the New York Yankees [signed free agent CC Sabathia to a 7 year deal worth $161 million](http://www.espn.com/mlb/news/story?id=3759182).  At the time, Sabathia was coming off winning the Cy Young Award, and was brought in to be the team's ace as their earlier championship core [aged and/or moved on](http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/2008.shtml#all_team_pitching).

However, after occasional short-term injuries earlier in his career, by 2014, a degenerative knee was placing Sabathia's [career in doubt](http://nypost.com/2014/07/04/sabathias-career-in-peril-with-threat-of-microfracture-surgery/).

At the time he was 33, and still [owed a great deal of money](http://www.beyondtheboxscore.com/2015/7/12/8932445/cc-sabathia-yankees-contract-sunk-cost) ($23 million each in 2014 and 2015, and $25 million in 2016).

My guess that the Yankees would have protected themselves by buying insurance [proved correct](http://www.nj.com/yankees/index.ssf/2014/07/how_much_money_yankees_would_save_if_cc_sabathia_retires.html).

He ended up returning to a fairly full load in 2015 and 2016... but [his best was certainly behind him](http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/s/sabatc.01.shtml).

But it got me wondering: how much might player insurance cost?  And how much more might it cost for Sabathia (since he was older and weighed 240 pounds) than for another player with a similar salary? Put another way: How much does Sabathia's "extra" age and weight cost in insurance?

Comment: [This article](http://www.sportsbusinessdaily.com/Daily/Issues/2008/05/Issue-162/Leagues-Governing-Bodies/MLB-Teams-Insure-Long-Term-Deals-To-Protect-From-Player-Injury.aspx) from 2008 discusses MLB team insurance on long-term players against injury.  The article mentions premiums "as high as 10% of the contracts annual value," and CC Sabathia has got to be on the upper end of that scale.

Comment: Insurance is also important in many other sports. More information on player insurance as a whole, and how often it is bought (in baseball, or in sports in general) would be very useful answers to such a question as this!